# Prove that MSE of $T_1$ is less than MSE of $T_2$

Tags: estimators, mse

Supposing that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d with distribution $X_i \sim Bin(m_i,\theta) i=1,...,n$ where $m_i$ are positive integers. 
Consider the estimators of $\theta$

$T_1(X) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i}$ and
$T_2(X) = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{X_i}{m_i}$

Prove that $ MSE(T_1) < MSE(T_2)$.

I have found that $ MSE(T_1) = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i}$ and $MSE(T_2) = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}1/m_i}$, but I couldn't prove that $\frac{n \sum_{i=1}^{n}1/m_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i}$ is less than 1.

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  This looks like a [tag:self-study] question.  If that is the case, please tag your question appropriately and read the associated [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: The expression for $MSE(T_2)$ looks incorrect.

Comment: Yes, You're right. Actually $MSE(T_2) = \frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}1/m_i$

Comment: Correcting the expression of $MSE(T_2)$ I could prove this using that $(\sum a_i b_i)^2 \le (\sum a_i^2)(\sum b_i^2)$.
Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $m_i\geq 1$. So:

$$n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{m_i}\leq n\leq\sum_{i=1}^n m_i.$$